# Changing the value of primeng switch. Instead of a boolean values I want the values be set to 'N' or 'Y'

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I used primeNg p-switch in my angular 2 project. The default values of primeNg input switch are set to boolean values. I want the the values of the input switch set to 'N' or 'Y' instead of true or false

```
@export class MyComponent{ 
         persons: Person[] = [{'name':'Marvin','legalAge': 'Y'}, {'name':'Carla','legalAge': 'N'} ] }
```

in the html template

```
<p-dataTable [value]="persons">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="legalAge" [sortable]="true" header="is Legal Age?">
        <template let-l="rowData" pTemplate>
                <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="l"></p-inputSwitch> 
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Any update on this? have u achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, this code

```
<my-stuff [(foo)]="bar"></my-stuff>
```

is just the syntactic sugar to write this:

```
 <my-stuff [foo]="bar" (fooChange)="bar = $event"></my-stuff>
```

Output from the bidirectional input is always made with the event with the `Change` suffix and `$event` as the value being assigned. Here `$event` is boolean.

Considering this you can use `p-inputSwitch` like that:

```
<p-inputSwitch
  [ngModel]="myProp === 'Y'"
  (ngModelChange)="myProp = $event ? 'Y' : 'N'"
></p-inputSwitch>
```

Though, I am not sure if it's a good idea to use string instead of normal booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise primeNg, like below example

```
<p-inputSwitch onLabel="Y" offLabel="N" [(ngModel)]="booleanString"></p-inputSwitch>
```

change model decleration as:

```
booleanString: boolean = true;
```

Please read the documentation carefully

Comment: If I well understood the question, @ilovejavaAJ want to bind the input switch to a string (rather than a boolean), this string will be either "Y" or "N". He don't want to change the label. Am i right ?

Comment: @AdrienBARRAL that's exactly what I wanted to do. The booleanString variable let say comes from a service and should always be a string not a boolean. My problem is the value that primeNG switch accepts is a boolean not a string.

Comment: I updated my question. I used primeNg input switch inside a primeNg table

Answer (score 0):

Since `PrimeNG inputSwitch` does only bind as `boolean`, So you need to have a change event function and bind your `string` value to new property.

You can do it with `(ngModelChange)` or by `(onChange)="handleChange($event)"` mentioned on there [website](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputswitch).

See this working [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZhjjCtv1U0KQXJd8VYcZ?p=preview).

updated plunker for DataTable module. : [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/doPmyzPrsEf7Mh3QVNlT?p=preview)

Comment: How can I apply that on my problem. I'm using primeng switch inside a table

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ : In this case, you can create another mapped array, example `newPersons`, and place a `boolean` flag there, then `onChange` assign `Y/N`. See this updated  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/doPmyzPrsEf7Mh3QVNlT?p=preview)

Comment: in your plunkr you've created a copy of the original array. changes in the values of switch are detected to the copied array. but I want ito reflect the changes o  switch directly to the original array

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ : I created separate array to keep separate the changed array from original, but if you want changes in original array, its absolutely no problem also. See this updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eMzqplDtLEvRJQhU6vKo?p=preview). `(onChange)` event i update the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="l" [trueValue]="'Y'" [falseValue]="'N'"></p-inputSwitch>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining why and how this will solve the problem. Code-only answers are to be avoided.

Comment: [trueValue]="'Y'" [falseValue]="'N'"

These will make it work.